# How to use Single sign on (SSO) using Microsoft Graph API on Office/Outlook Web sessions?

Tags: outlook, office365, adal, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a working oauth2 application using v1.0 of Azure REST API. I am able to acquire access token via ADAL library for Java and no problem accessing their resources.

However, I wanted to know if there is a way to use this same token in order to let Office365/Outlook users to login on a web browser without entering a password ? Something like https://outlook.office365.com/token=abc..

This will help us to let users SSO on different devices without typing their passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes you can. You can try to leverage [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/call_api) to achieve your requirement.

1. Add the permission of Microsoft Graph in your AAD application, refer to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview for more info.
2. Follow OAuth2's Authorization Code Grant Flow to generate an access token, or leveraging your ADAL, please refer to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization for details.
3. Set the access token in the request header the same as you call Azure Rest APIs.

   ```
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/john.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com HTTP/1.1
   Authorization : Bearer <access_token>
   ```

For outlook APIs, you can refer to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message for more info.

Comment: I have an access token that is valid. Are you saying GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/john.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com HTTP/1.1
Authorization : Bearer <access_token> will get me a SSO link or it will open outlook on the browser? The main idea is trying to use the token (or another one) to login users w/o asking them to sign in